# Laravels foreach output is not complete

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-blade

I wrote an eloquent statement in my model that outputs a whole lot of data which is fully modelled for my output. It returns the right content when I dump it in the backend (if you look at the comment below).

But when I try to get it formatted with blade for my table, it cuts a whole lot of data at the top. It starts somewhere at the mid of all.

I tried a lot of styling like put some standard CSS from bootstrap and nothing at all, because I thought that this is a display error, but it seems not.

#### Route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $hs = App\Wl_steige::all()->first();
    $hs = $hs->getByStation('ptMetro')->groupBy('BEZEICHNUNG');
    //dump($hs = $hs->getByStation('ptMetro')->groupBy('BEZEICHNUNG'))
    return view('welcome', ['stellen' => collect($hs)]);
});
```

#### View:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <tbody>
                @foreach($stellen AS $line => $stations)
                <tr>
                    <th>Linie {{ $line }}</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($stations AS $station)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $station->NAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $station->VERKEHRSMITTEL }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $station->RBL_NUMMER }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $station->STEIG_WGS84_LAT }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $station->STEIG_WGS84_LON }}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expected that it would begin at the top and not somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a "hidden" `text-align: center;` from the former Laravel template which - I dont know why but made my text float out of the screen. 
I didnt saw it at first because it was somewhere Cached. 
After I cleared at first hand Laravels cache files `php artisan cache:clear` and then `Cmd + R` for Chrome, it worked fine for me.